# solving SIGABRT error in cocos2d code

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics, sigabrt, box2d-iphone

I don't know what i've done wrong. I get a SIGABRT error and I guess it's got to do with the for loop in the code below. Could someone please help me out. Thanks in Advance.

```
b2BodyDef ropeBodyDef;
    ropeBodyDef.linearDamping = 0.2;
    ropeBodyDef.angularDamping = 0.2;
    ropeBodyDef.userData = ropeSprite;
    b2Body *ropeBody;
    b2Body *ropeStart = starBody;
    b2MassData ropeMassData;
    ropeMassData.mass = 1;
    ropeBody->GetMassData(&ropeMassData);

    b2DistanceJointDef ropeJointDef;
    b2DistanceJoint *ropeJoint;
    float dY = starBody->GetPosition().y - fittingBody->GetPosition().y;
    int numSections = ceil(dY/ 55);
    for (float i = 0; i < numSections - 1; i++) {
        // one rope section body

        ropeBodyDef.position.Set(0, starBody->GetPosition().y - dY * i/numSections);
        ropeMassData.mass = 0.8 + 0.8 * i / numSections;

        // rope body
        ropeBody = world->CreateBody(&ropeBodyDef);
        ropeFixture = ropeBody->CreateFixture(&ropeShapeDef);

        [ropeSegments addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:ropeBody]];

        // one rope section to another
        ropeJointDef.Initialize(ropeStart, ropeBody, ropeStart->GetPosition(), ropeBody->GetPosition());
        ropeJoint = (b2DistanceJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&ropeJointDef);
        ropeJoint->SetLength(dY / numSections); 

        // update startpoint for next joint
        ropeStart = ropeBody;
    }

    // final rope joint
    ropeJointDef.Initialize(ropeStart, ropeBody, ropeStart->GetPosition(), ropeBody->GetPosition());
    ropeJoint = (b2DistanceJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&ropeJointDef); // THIS IS THE LINE THAT I GET THE SIGABRT 
    ropeJoint->SetLength(dY / numSections); 

    [ropeSegments addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:fittingBody]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just declare `ropeBody` the first line below and you already call a method on it without initializing and assigning its value:

```
b2Body *ropeBody; <-- declare here
b2Body *ropeStart = starBody;
b2MassData ropeMassData;
ropeMassData.mass = 1;
ropeBody->GetMassData(&ropeMassData); <-- uh, ropeBody is null or rubbish pointer
```

Comment: Please take a look at [the full code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805620/exc-bad-access-with-cocos2d-box2d-code) to put things in perspective

Comment: What things? What perspective? If you want better perspective you should just indicate which exact line causes the error.

Comment: In the full code I declared all bodies including the ropeBody.

Comment: Variables declaration is different from instantiation. Look it up and digest the meaning first. Just because you declare it doesn't mean it already has a value. Imagine you declare a `b2Body *b` .. then suddenly you want do `b->GetPosition()` what would you get? You get rubbish if not runtime error because `b` is not a valid b2Body yet. You need to instantiate it: `b = world->CreateBody(...)` .. that's what I don't see in your code.

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks. I've made the correction, but I am still getting a SIGABRT error pointing to the line `ropeJoint = (b2DistanceJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&ropeJointDef);` after the for loop